# nodejs mongodb storing a variable from a function when posting a new row

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fs, readfile

Hello I have a mongodb table and working with multer file upload
Im using readFile for the file im uploading and searching for certain words in lines
This is my **POST API**

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    function fileToString() {
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
        if(step.includes("step")){
        console.log(step);
        return step;
        }
    });
     }
     
    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        run: fileToString(), //this variable is the one i want to store the result of the function in
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

The **function fileToString()** is functional and it the console returns what I need
However I want whatever the returned Value to be directly stored into the variable **run** when i run my create API and add a new row to the table
How can I do that please I'm new to nodejs and mongodb

Comment: please also add your insertOne / insertMany method call

Comment: also provide implementation of `Testcase` class

Comment: I'm not using insertOne / insertMany method, the one I posted is how i insert into my database, I added my module and the implementation in another reply can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is my module

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const testcaseSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required : true , unique : true},
    upload: String,
    run: String,
    modify: String,
    delete: String,
    step1: String,
    step2: String,
    step3: String,
    step4: String,
    step5: String,
    step6: String,
    step7: String,
    checked: { type: Boolean, default: false }

    
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('testcase', testcaseSchema, 'testcases');
```

Here is the implementation and how i upload the file

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const  ls  = require('child_process');
const multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

const  Testcase  = require('../modules/testcase');

//File Upload
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        -callBack(null, "./uploads/");
        +callBack(null, "uploads/")
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        //callBack(null, `FunOfHeuristic_${file.originalname}`)
        const name = file.originalname
        callBack(null, name); 
    }
})
```